# Wrapper program that sets signal handler

Tags: bash, signals, system-calls, trap

I would like to have a wrapper program that runs a given command and sets a signal handler so that it gets run when the command receives a specified signal.

The question is this:

1. Is there an utility program to do this?
2. If not, is it possible to do this by using bash's commands `trap` and `exec`?
3. If not, how can I do this? (e.g. by writing a program myself in C which does a few system calls)

EDIT: The target platform is GNU/Linux.

EDIT 2: Following Ignacio's answer, I managed to write a preload SO which looks like [this](http://codepad.org/vHKAumdb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done. From the `exec(3p)` man page:

> Signals  set to be caught by the calling process image shall be set to the
>          default action in the  new  process  image.

You would have to write a preload SO which would hook up the signal handlers before the program started.

Comment: Is that true?  The [GNU implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/nohup.c) of nohup(1) calls signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN) followed by exec(3), and it can effectively make the run command immune to SIGHUP.

Comment: `SIG_IGN` is not "caught". "Except  for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image."

Comment: Thanks.  (I should have read the POSIX document more carefully.)  As for a preload shared object to do this, do I have to write it myself?  I think such an SO is versatile, and suspect there exist a well-known library to do this.

Comment: The thing of it is that you have to write the signal handlers yourself, so it would end up being a mostly custom job regardless.

Comment: All I would like the signal handler to do is execute a shell command, so a general-purpose SO would be useful.  But it seems such an SO does not exist, and I have to write it myself anyway.

Comment: @Pteromys And the reason a program can't set a signal handler for another program is that the code would execute in the program where it resides. If the process calls `execve`, all of its code and data is freed from memory, so it can't be used for a signal handler any more.

Answer (score 1):

You could only have it ignore signals (`SIG_IGN`); you wouldn't be able to give a signal handler either from the shell (`trap`) or within a C program (`signal(2)`).  When exec is called, any signal handler would be replaced.

Example:

```
:
trap "" 1 2
exec sleep 100000
```

Then call the program, either in the background or fore, and send either a `SIGHUP` or `SIGINT` to the program.  It is ignored.  Putting code in the trap causes signal to be reset on exec:

```
:
trap "echo signal caught" 1 2
exec sleep 10000
```

This won't print "signal caught" of you send the signals, but will in fact terminate the program.